# Serve [different] static HTML from Bottle when JavaScript is not enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, url-rewriting, url-routing, bottle

How do I serve different files from Bottle based on client JavaScript being enabled?

One hacky solution I can think of is to:

- Serve static html by default; include a simple JavaScript action which if triggered, redirects to the JavaScript page

Unfortunately this would result in different URL paths.

Is there an equivalent method which will serve either page [based on JavaScript being enabled] from `/`?

Maybe by using JavaScript to rewrite the `document`?

Comment: Note that I am using the Python WSGI HTTP Server: [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).

Comment: Similar: serve static page, clear and rewrite its contents by AJAX. Tadaa, same URL.

Comment: Good timing; just edited my question with that possibility then I got your comment notification :). Hmm, yes that is a great option. Will investigate the precise syntax, but am guessing that I would put the JS dependencies at the bottom of the `<body>`… as is usually recommended anyway.